# Outlook: Disable "Contacting the server for information"

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a click bot that processes Outlook message files.

```
├───folder1
│       message.msg
│
├───folder2
│       message.msg
│
└───[...]
```

Usually, Outlook opens the messages just fine. Sometimes, though—consistently for certain messages—it hangs on a progress dialog with the message:

> Contacting the server for information.

[image: Contacting the server for information.]

Outlook is connected to an Exchange email account on this machine.

Is there a way to disable Outlook's attempt to contact the server?

Comment: How would Outlook send and receive email if you prevent it from contacting the server?

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica In this case, it doesn't need to send or receive, only open `.msg` files that are already on the disk.

Comment: Have you disabled the check for send/receive? Press Ctrl+Alt+S and uncheck "Schedule an automatic send and receive every mm minutes".

Comment: That info belongs in your question. Do you have an email account configured in the Outlook client? If so, what type?

Comment: When you open messages, Outlook may attempt to contact your email server to retrieve emails or attachments or attempt to download images from HTML email messages. Reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-am-i-getting-the-message-contacting-the-server-for-information-973c8d98-4d22-49b5-bc66-0d9d87783f99

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica Added....

Comment: @harrymc It doesn't seem to be related to send/receive. It happens consistently when opening certain `.msg` files.

Comment: @Aidan Hmm...so [changing the Automatic Download settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/block-or-unblock-automatic-picture-downloads-in-email-messages-15e08854-6808-49b1-9a0a-50b81f2d617a) to "Don't download pictures automatically" might solve it?

Comment: @Aidan But the problem is, I still need to include inline images....I'm just baffled why it takes so long on certain messages that don't even contain large images. Maybe there's a way to save message that embeds whatever content Outlook is looking for.